# Is function from $L^{1}$ spaces

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f,g \in L^{1}(R)$, and $h(t)= \int _{R}f(x-t)g(x)dx$. Prove that h is almost everywhere finite. Does function $h$ has to be in $L^{1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows immediately from [Young's Inequality for convolutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_convolution_inequality). Let $r=p=q=1$ so that $1+1/r=1/p+1/q$, so that:

$$\|h\|_1\leq \|f\|_1\|g\|_1,$$

so $h(t)$ is integrable and therefore finite almost everywhere.

Comment: [Please review carefully the Enforcement of Quality Standards Policy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNLhxKpfCnA). Try to refrain from answering very low quality questions with no context.